# Drop rows based on conditions and create new columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
      Trade #     Segnale          Data/Ora  Prezzo
0        1        Long  2022-01-12 14:00   43302
1        1   Exit Long  2022-01-12 22:00   44169
2        2       Short  2022-01-14 12:00   42093
3        2  Exit short  2022-01-14 15:00   42514
```

You can reproduce with:

```
tbl2 = {"Trade #" :[1,1,2,2],
       "Segnale" : ["Long", "Exit Long", "Short", "Exit short"],
       "Data/Ora" : ["2022-01-12 14:00", "2022-01-12 22:00", "2022-01-14 12:00",
                     "2022-01-14 15:00"],
        "Prezzo" : [43302, 44169, 42093, 42514]}

df = pd.DataFrame(tbl2)
```

My goal is to drop the rows if "Segnale" column has ("Exit Long" OR "Exit short") as row
take the "Data/Ora" and "Prezzo" row and create two columns with that values names Data/Ora_exit and Prezzo_exit,

This is how it should look like the final dataframe:

```
df2

 Trade #     Segnale             Data/Ora   Prezzo   Data/Ora_exit            Prezzo_exit
       1    Long          2022-01-12 14:00  43302    2022-01-12 22:00            44169
         
       2    Short          2022-01-14 12:00 42093     2022-01-14 15:00           42514
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Use `Series.isin` or `Series.str.startswith` or `Series.str.match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
m=df[(df['Segnale'].isin(['Exit Long', 'Exit short']))].add_suffix('_exit')
pd.concat([df, m.iloc[:,2:]], axis=1).groupby('Trade').first()
```

OR

```
m=df.mask(df['Segnale'].isin(['Exit Long', 'Exit short'])).add_suffix('_exit')
(pd.concat([df,m.iloc[:,2:]], axis=1)).dropna()
```

```
    Segnale     Data/Ora    Prezzo  Data/Ora_exit   Prezzo_exit
Trade                   
1   Long    2022-01-12 14:00    43302   2022-01-12 22:00    44169.0
2   Short   2022-01-14 12:00    42093   2022-01-14 15:00    42514.0
```

Comment: Good Attempt. What if suppose the order is changed?

Comment: Thanks @MohamedThasinah, order of what? If 'Segnale' and 'data/ora', are not the first two columns, then solution needs to be updated.

Comment: I am not talking about column order. I am interested in row order. Your code expects X, Exit X. If the row order is random, it could create a big trouble.

Comment: OP will be able to comment on the order of the data, however, it seems to be that row order has a logical sequencing, as in provided in the question, and it can further be ensured with  df.sort_values(['Trade','Data/Ora'])

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
df = df.groupby('Trade #').agg({'Data/Ora': ['min', 'max'], 'Prezzo': ['min', 'max'], 'Segnale': 'first'})
df.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

O/P:

```
   Trade #      Data/Ora_min      Data/Ora_max  Prezzo_min  Prezzo_max  \
0        1  2022-01-12 14:00  2022-01-12 22:00       43302       44169   
1        2  2022-01-14 12:00  2022-01-14 15:00       42093       42514   

  Segnale_first  
0          Long  
1         Short
```

Note: Rename/Reorder columns as you desire

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.iloc[::2, :].merge(
    df.iloc[1::2, :].rename(columns={'Data/Ora': 'Data/Ora exit', 'Prezzo': 'Prezzo exit'}).drop('Segnale', axis=1), on='Trade #'
)
```